# Reference image disappears

Tags: image, transparency

I imported an image as reference and it isn't visible. When I hover around where it should be, a yellow square appears and I can select it but I cannot get an image to appear in it.
I tried it again and the image showed up as expected I began sculpting, togling the image visibility in the scene collection as neaded and now it wont apear anymore. I can still select the yellow outline and change its setting in the object data properties but I cannot get the image to reapear.

It still apeares as an empty in the scene collection
Filetype jpg
File path is corect
Viewing in material preview in the 3D viewport

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, what format is the image? How exactly did you import it? Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us 
understand your scene and settings.  See [How to upload an image to a 
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: maybe it's a bug? Please pack your image and share the file (with only the Reference Image): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I came across this question because this kept happening to me - I don't know why this worked, but unchecking and rechecking the Collection in the Scene Collection fixed this. I'm fairly new to Blender, a 'donut graduate'! Hopefully someone can explain why this happened? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tESK.png